# Trouble parsing deeply-nested HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

for context I am pretty new to Python. I am trying to use bs4 to parse some data out of https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/university-of-california-los-angeles

To be exact, I want to obtain the 57% number in the "paying" section of the webpage.
My problem is that bs4 will only return the first layer of the HTML, while the data I want is deeply nested in the code. I think it's under 17 divs.

Here is my python code:

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/university-of-california-los-angeles'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("div", {"id": "gwtDiv"}))
```

(This returns `[<div class="clearfix margin60 marginBottomOnly" id="gwtDiv" style="min-height: 300px;height: 300px;height: auto;"></div>]` None of the elements inside it are shown.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is using js to render content inside the element then requests will not be able to get that content since that content is rendered on the client side in a browser. I'd recommend using ChromeDriver and Selenium along with BeautifulSoup.

You can download the chrome driver from here:https://chromedriver.chromium.org/
Put this in the same folder in which you're running your program.

Try something like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/college-university-search/university-of-california-los-angeles'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
sel_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all("div", {"id": "gwtDiv"}))
```